# Auth0.js - Why make second call to /userinfo in parseHash?

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0

In the Auth0 docs (link [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9#extract-the-authresult-and-get-user-info)), the following example is given for retrieving user info after parsing the access token, id token and expiry from the URI:

```
webAuth.parseHash({ hash: window.location.hash }, function(err, authResult) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  webAuth.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(err, user) {
    // Now you have the user's information
  });
});
```

I don't understand what the use of the call to `webAuth.client.userInfo()` is. When viewing the contents of `authResult` as passed to the callback for `parseHash()` there appears to be a property called `idTokenPayload` that already includes all the user information.

In fact, when looking at the network log it appears that `parseHash()` is making its own call to `/userinfo` to retrieve the full user information and include it in the `authResult` object passed to the callback.

Why then do the docs suggest that you repeat the call to `/userinfo` and get the user information again? Isn't this redundant?

Comment: I have the same question, did you get any clarity on this?

Comment: @gorillapower See [this](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/599) github issue.